# Derivation of formula for square of scalar triple product in terms of determinant of dot products

Tags: vectors, determinant

Can anyone provide or link me to a derivation of

$$ (\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{c})^2 = \begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{a \cdot a} & \mathbf{a \cdot b} & \mathbf{a\cdot c}\\ 
\mathbf{b\cdot a} & \mathbf{b\cdot b} & \mathbf{b\cdot c}\\ 
\mathbf{c \cdot a} & \mathbf{c \cdot b} & \mathbf{c \cdot c}
\end{vmatrix} $$

Preferably without using anything more advanced than the various identities for triple products, determinants and matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $E$ be the $3\times 3$ matrix $\left[\begin{matrix}\mathbf{a} \\ \mathbf{b} \\ \mathbf{c}  \end{matrix}\right].$ It is well known that $(\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}) \cdot \mathbf{c} = |E|.$ Therefore, $((\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}) \cdot \mathbf{c})^2=|E|^2=|EE^T|=$ your RHS.

Comment: This answer really isn't particularly helpful, seeing as it doesn't answer the question